# Why does spread operator at CodePen and Chrome have different results?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, codepen

I tested the spread operator at CodePen and in Chrome and I got different result.

```
var str = 'foo';
var char = [...str];
console.log(char);
```

At CodePen I used the Babel  preprocessor and got `["foo"]`.

In Chrome developer tools, I got `["f", "o", "o"]`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: works fine : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brdqGw?editors=1111

Comment: @SureshAtta I used Babel preprocessor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, this is related to babel js transpiler.
Looks like codepen is using this babel-preset `es2015-loose` and it has some divergences in its spread operator implementation:

> Babel’s loose mode transpiles ES6 code to ES5 code that is less
>   faithful to ES6 semantics.

source: http://2ality.com/2015/12/babel6-loose-mode.html

This is actually a codepen issue, they probably shouldn't be using `loose` mode these days.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference here between the code compiled by Codepen and JS Bin.

Codepen compiled:

```
'use strict';

var str = 'foo';
var char = [].concat(str);
alert(char);
```

JS Bin compiled:

```
try {
'use strict';

    function _toConsumableArray(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) { for (var i = 0, arr2 = Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) arr2[i] = arr[i]; return arr2; } else { return Array.from(arr); } }

    var str = 'foo';
    var char = [].concat(_toConsumableArray(str));
    window.runnerWindow.proxyConsole.log(char);
} catch (error) { throw error; }
```